# Git Rebase a feature branch to the tip of a feature branch

Tags: git

I have a repo with a master, devel, and feature branch. When I made the feature, I branched it off of the most up to date version of the devel branch at the time. There's been changes to feature and devel in separate areas mostly, so rebasing should be easy. What command do I use for git to apply the changes from devel onto feature. It should look like this:

```
          o feature
         /                         Initial creation
   o----o devel                    of feature
  /
 o----o----o----o----o master

           |
           V

          o----o----o feature
         /                         Changes are made
   o----o----o----o----o devel     to both branches
  /
 o----o----o----o----o master

          |
          V

                         o----o----o feature
                        /                      Feature is given the
   o----o----o----o----o devel                 changes made on the
  /                                            devel branch
 o----o----o----o----o master
```

Feel free to ask questions, I'm new to rebasing with git, so my model might be wrong from what I'm looking for.

Comment: `git rebase devel feature`?

Comment: I've tried that, but the commits weren't added.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was simple, I needed to do a `git pull` to get my local copy of devel up to date. Then when I do `git rebase devel feature`, it finally took those changes. Neat.